# Windows and Linux "dual boot" or simultaneously (similar to bootcamp) on same PC

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, boot-camp

Not sure if the "dual boot" correct wording for what I wish to achieve. but I'll have a go and please correct me if I am wrong.

I am a developer and I wish to have a PC with Both windows and Linux Os running at the same time because of the development requirements. I know few ways to do is for e.g. using virtualization but I wish to avoid this if possible.

I have briefly come across bootcamp which is an Apple product, and it looks like it allows you to easily switch between OSX and other OS. The whole user experience seemed very intuitive.

I was wondering if there's something similar possible with Windows and Linux?

Edit: following looks the nearest the one I am looking for..

https://www.parallels.com/uk/cross-platform-solutions/

Any input?

Thanks

Comment: Hardware management should be done by one King (Only one OS). That is the issue.

Comment: @user25018: with bootcamp you are not running macosx and $other-os here at the same time: you have to pick which ONE you want to boot at, well, boot-time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [simple tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Dual-boot-Linux-and-Windows-on-a-PC-with-W/). This is not complicated at all. On your pc you just install both windows and linux, and you choos which system to run on starup.

If you want to have access to both operating system without need of restarting, best solution is to use virtual machine like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). There are plenty of tutorials out there depending on what you want to do (virtual linux on windows or other way around). I could not past links due to my low reputation on this site.

Comment: I think this answer misunderstood the question. Bootcamp allows a user to switch between OSs without rebooting.